# Extract data from tables using scrapy

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy

I am extracting data from this website:
http://www.tablebuilder.singstat.gov.sg/publicfacing/createDataTable.action?refId=1907&exportType=csv

I am using scrapy to extract the data of the GDP that is stated in it. My code is as follows:

```
class DmozSpider(Spider):
name = "gdp"
allowed_domains = ["singstat.gov.org"]
start_urls = [
    "http://www.tablebuilder.singstat.gov.sg/publicfacing/createDataTable.action?refId=1907&exportType=csv",
]

def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//tr[@class="RowOdd"]/td[@class="TextRow1 divResize"]/div[@class="varNameClass"]')
    items = []

    for site in sites:
        item = Website()
        item['value'] = site.xpath('td[@class="TextRowRight divResize"]/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)

    return items
```

I started from tr class="RowOdd", td class="TextRow1 divResize" and slowly reaching the last tag . Afterwhich, I should get the gdp value = 654.8 but there is nothing printed to the file.

Kindly help thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the same site with Scrapy as in the browser? I executed a simple scrape and for me it seems that I get some other information back than the table in the browser. `<title>Selection of Variables | SingStat Table Builder</title>`

Comment: what u mean? can elaborate more?

Comment: what should be the possible output you need ? Is it GDP from 1975 to 2015 ?

Comment: I printed the contents of the response to the console with `print response.body`. There I have some output with the title in my previous comment -- with different contents like in the browser. The title is different too of course. If I look through the response body I see that there is no sign of `RowOdd` there. And if I save the contents and open this site it is a way different from the table (perhaps the data is loaded with AJAX).

Comment: @Jithin Yes but it is possible to only concentrate on 2014 Q1-Q4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its actually a form request which is fetching the data,

see the demo from the scrapy shell

```
In [1]: from scrapy.http import FormRequest 

In [2]: url = 'http://www.tablebuilder.singstat.gov.sg/publicfacing/createDataTable.action?refId=1907'

In [3]: form_data = {
'struts.token.name':'token',
'token':'1Z6NS7BWFOD0ARQH160MLHZ1FZF5ZKBB',
'titleId':'4646',
'subjectName':'',
'topicName':'',
'titleName':'M013751 - Gross Domestic Product At Current Market Prices, By Industry, Quarterly',
'glosDiv':'',
'groupVarIds':'1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;',
'selectedVarIds': ['93204','93350','93180','93376','93158','93272','93087','92926','93275','93144','93248','93170','92946','93065','93136','93283','93296'],
'selectedTimeIds': ['702','703','704','705','706','707','708','709','710','711','712','713','714','715','716','717','718','719','720','721','722','723','724','725','726','727','728','729','730','731','732','733','734','735','736','737','738','739','740','741','742','743','744','745','746','747','748','749','750','751','752','753','754','755','756','757','758','759','760','761','762','763','764','765','211','212','213','214','187','188','189','190','191','192','193','194','195','196','197','198','199','200','201','202','203','204','205','206','207','208','209','210','104','105','106','107','108','109','110','111','112','113','114','115','116','117','118','119','120','121','122','123','124','125','126','127','128','129','130','131','132','133','134','135','136','137','138','139','140','141','142','143','144','103','21','22','23','24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32','33','34','1','2','3','4','5','6','17','175','179','184','217','222','943'],
}

In [4]: request_object = FormRequest(url=url, formdata=form_data)

In [5]: fetch(request_object) 
2015-07-07 17:06:24+0530 [default] INFO: Spider opened
2015-07-07 17:06:26+0530 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://www.tablebuilder.singstat.gov.sg/publicfacing/createDataTable.action?refId=1907> (referer: None)
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x7f77a9293250>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request_object <POST http://www.tablebuilder.singstat.gov.sg/publicfacing/createDataTable.action?refId=1907>
[s]   request    <POST http://www.tablebuilder.singstat.gov.sg/publicfacing/createDataTable.action?refId=1907>
[s]   response   <200 http://www.tablebuilder.singstat.gov.sg/publicfacing/createDataTable.action?refId=1907>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x7f77b11e8450>
[s]   spider     <Spider 'default' at 0x7f77a6274b50>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser

In [6]: sites = response.xpath('//tr[@class="RowOdd"]/td[@class="TextRow1 divResize"]/div[@class="varNameClass"]')   

In [7]: sites
Out[7]: 
[<Selector xpath='//tr[@class="RowOdd"]/td[@class="TextRow1 divResize"]/div[@class="varNameClass"]' data=u'<div class="varNameClass" style="display'>,
 <Selector xpath='//tr[@class="RowOdd"]/td[@class="TextRow1 divResize"]/div[@class="varNameClass"]' data=u'<div class="varNameClass" style="display'>,
 <Selector xpath='//tr[@class="RowOdd"]/td[@class="TextRow1 divResize"]/div[@class="varNameClass"]' data=u'<div class="varNameClass" style="display'>,
 <Selector xpath='//tr[@class="RowOdd"]/td[@class="TextRow1 divResize"]/div[@class="varNameClass"]' data=u'<div class="varNameClass" style="display'>,
 <Selector xpath='//tr[@class="RowOdd"]/td[@class="TextRow1 divResize"]/div[@class="varNameClass"]' data=u'<div class="varNameClass" style="display'>,
 <Selector xpath='//tr[@class="RowOdd"]/td[@class="TextRow1 divResize"]/div[@class="varNameClass"]' data=u'<div class="varNameClass" style="display'>,
 <Selector xpath='//tr[@class="RowOdd"]/td[@class="TextRow1 divResize"]/div[@class="varNameClass"]' data=u'<div class="varNameClass" style="display'>,
 <Selector xpath='//tr[@class="RowOdd"]/td[@class="TextRow1 divResize"]/div[@class="varNameClass"]' data=u'<div class="varNameClass" style="display'>,
 <Selector xpath='//tr[@class="RowOdd"]/td[@class="TextRow1 divResize"]/div[@class="varNameClass"]' data=u'<div class="varNameClass" style="display'>]
```

a sample output would be,

```
table_headers = response.xpath('//tr[@class="BackGroundTRHeader"]/th/a/text()').extract()
table_headers = [i.strip() for i in table_headers if i.strip()][1:]
values = response.xpath('//tr[td[div[@class="varNameClass" and contains(text(), "Gross Domestic Product At Current Market Prices")]]]/td[@class="TextRowRight divResize"]')
gdp_values = []
for value in values:
    data = value.xpath('.//text()').extract()
    data = data[0].strip() if data else ''
    gdp_values.append(data)

processed_data = dict(zip(table_headers, gdp_values))
```

if you print the processed data,

```
{u'1975 1Q': u'3,209.2',
 u'1975 2Q': u'3,306.9',
 u'1975 3Q': u'3,519.1',
 u'1975 4Q': u'3,692.8',
 u'1976 1Q': u'3,544.8',
 u'1976 2Q': u'3,619.9',
 u'1976 3Q': u'3,846.2',
 u'1976 4Q': u'3,991',
 u'1977 1Q': u'3,872.8',
 u'1977 2Q': u'3,962.4',
 u'1977 3Q': u'4,171.8',
 u'1977 4Q': u'4,343.6',
 u'1978 1Q': u'4,283.5',
 u'1978 2Q': u'4,376.2',
 u'1978 3Q': u'4,694.9',
 u'1978 4Q': u'4,979.5',
 u'1979 1Q': u'4,767.3',
 u'1979 2Q': u'5,060.3',
 u'1979 3Q': u'5,459.9',
 u'1979 4Q': u'5,848.5',
 u'1980 1Q': u'6,015.7',
 u'1980 2Q': u'6,245.1',
 u'1980 3Q': u'6,616.4',
 u'1980 4Q': u'6,986.2',
 u'1981 1Q': u'6,972.6',
 u'1981 2Q': u'7,296.5',
 u'1981 3Q': u'7,843.4',
 u'1981 4Q': u'8,232.2',
 u'1982 1Q': u'8,062.2',
 u'1982 2Q': u'8,196.3',
 u'1982 3Q': u'8,613.8',
 u'1982 4Q': u'9,097.5',
 u'1983 1Q': u'8,811.7',
 u'1983 2Q': u'9,324.9',
 u'1983 3Q': u'9,792.7',
 u'1983 4Q': u'10,109.8',
 u'1984 1Q': u'9,925.5',
 u'1984 2Q': u'10,219.3',
 u'1984 3Q': u'10,661',
 u'1984 4Q': u'10,896.2',
 u'1985 1Q': u'10,430.6',
 u'1985 2Q': u'10,171.1',
 u'1985 3Q': u'10,210.2',
 u'1985 4Q': u'10,012',
 u'1986 1Q': u'9,757.9',
 u'1986 2Q': u'9,952',
 u'1986 3Q': u'10,279.7',
 u'1986 4Q': u'10,864.7',
 u'1987 1Q': u'10,418.7',
 u'1987 2Q': u'10,971.1',
 u'1987 3Q': u'11,712.3',
 u'1987 4Q': u'12,400.4',
 u'1988 1Q': u'12,092.2',
 u'1988 2Q': u'12,837.7',
 u'1988 3Q': u'13,785.3',
 u'1988 4Q': u'14,645',
 u'1989 1Q': u'13,934.7',
 u'1989 2Q': u'14,834.3',
 u'1989 3Q': u'15,768.8',
 u'1989 4Q': u'16,686.6',
 u'1990 1Q': u'16,678',
 u'1990 2Q': u'17,091',
 u'1990 3Q': u'17,932.5',
 u'1990 4Q': u'18,805.8',
 u'1991 1Q': u'18,529.5',
 u'1991 2Q': u'19,061.1',
 u'1991 3Q': u'20,153',
 u'1991 4Q': u'20,813.5',
 u'1992 1Q': u'19,964.2',
 u'1992 2Q': u'20,392.8',
 u'1992 3Q': u'21,688.7',
 u'1992 4Q': u'22,917.1',
 u'1993 1Q': u'22,574.9',
 u'1993 2Q': u'23,650.6',
 u'1993 3Q': u'24,994.8',
 u'1993 4Q': u'26,769.2',
 u'1994 1Q': u'26,326.5',
 u'1994 2Q': u'26,984.7',
 u'1994 3Q': u'29,076.8',
 u'1994 4Q': u'30,300.2',
 u'1995 1Q': u'28,961',
 u'1995 2Q': u'30,135.2',
 u'1995 3Q': u'32,098.4',
 u'1995 4Q': u'33,380.7',
 u'1996 1Q': u'32,815.7',
 u'1996 2Q': u'33,215.7',
 u'1996 3Q': u'33,946.3',
 u'1996 4Q': u'35,951.6',
 u'1997 1Q': u'34,811.2',
 u'1997 2Q': u'36,854.3',
 u'1997 3Q': u'38,262.1',
 u'1997 4Q': u'38,795.9',
 u'1998 1Q': u'36,001.1',
 u'1998 2Q': u'35,849.6',
 u'1998 3Q': u'35,866.2',
 u'1998 4Q': u'35,723.4',
 u'1999 1Q': u'33,922.3',
 u'1999 2Q': u'36,198.4',
 u'1999 3Q': u'37,460.5',
 u'1999 4Q': u'38,668.7',
 u'2000 1Q': u'38,179.9',
 u'2000 2Q': u'39,924.5',
 u'2000 3Q': u'42,863.4',
 u'2000 4Q': u'44,249.9',
 u'2001 1Q': u'41,206.6',
 u'2001 2Q': u'39,935.7',
 u'2001 3Q': u'39,229.4',
 u'2001 4Q': u'39,602.4',
 u'2002 1Q': u'40,269.8',
 u'2002 2Q': u'41,052.3',
 u'2002 3Q': u'41,191.1',
 u'2002 4Q': u'42,116.7',
 u'2003 1Q': u'41,823.5',
 u'2003 2Q': u'39,845.9',
 u'2003 3Q': u'42,305.1',
 u'2003 4Q': u'45,021.3',
 u'2004 1Q': u'46,244.9',
 u'2004 2Q': u'46,348.7',
 u'2004 3Q': u'48,859.6',
 u'2004 4Q': u'51,548.3',
 u'2005 1Q': u'50,312.4',
 u'2005 2Q': u'51,013.6',
 u'2005 3Q': u'53,566.3',
 u'2005 4Q': u'57,181.7',
 u'2006 1Q': u'55,475',
 u'2006 2Q': u'56,931.4',
 u'2006 3Q': u'59,358.1',
 u'2006 4Q': u'63,070.5',
 u'2007 1Q': u'63,175.9',
 u'2007 2Q': u'66,580.6',
 u'2007 3Q': u'69,656.2',
 u'2007 4Q': u'71,837.1',
 u'2008 1Q': u'68,248.9',
 u'2008 2Q': u'67,898',
 u'2008 3Q': u'69,547.8',
 u'2008 4Q': u'66,285.7',
 u'2009 1Q': u'64,212.6',
 u'2009 2Q': u'67,670.2',
 u'2009 3Q': u'71,976.9',
 u'2009 4Q': u'75,998.3',
 u'2010 1Q': u'76,781.4',
 u'2010 2Q': u'80,025.8',
 u'2010 3Q': u'80,666.6',
 u'2010 4Q': u'84,887.3',
 u'2011 1Q': u'85,418.3',
 u'2011 2Q': u'85,495.4',
 u'2011 3Q': u'86,754.7',
 u'2011 4Q': u'88,685.1',
 u'2012 1Q': u'89,655.7',
 u'2012 2Q': u'90,819.3',
 u'2012 3Q': u'88,976.3',
 u'2012 4Q': u'92,881.2',
 u'2013 1Q': u'92,256.5',
 u'2013 2Q': u'93,680.9',
 u'2013 4Q': u'98,168.9',
 u'2014 1Q': u'96,368.3',
 u'2014 2Q': u'96,808.3',
 u'2014 3Q': u'97,382',
 u'2014 4Q': u'99,530.5',
 u'2015 1Q': u'98,743.3'}
```

**EDIT**

final code will look something like this,

```
class DmozSpider(Spider):
    name = "gdp"
    allowed_domains = ["singstat.gov.org"]
    url = 'http://www.tablebuilder.singstat.gov.sg/publicfacing/createDataTable.action?refId=1907'

    def start_requests(self):
        form_data = {
                    'struts.token.name': 'token',
                    'token': '1Z6NS7BWFOD0ARQH160MLHZ1FZF5ZKBB',
                    'titleId': '4646',
                    'subjectName': '',
                    'topicName': '',
                    'titleName': 'M013751 - Gross Domestic Product At Current Market Prices, By Industry, Quarterly',
                    'glosDiv': '',
                    'groupVarIds': '1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;',
                    'selectedVarIds': ['93204', '93350', '93180', '93376', '93158', '93272', '93087', '92926', '93275', '93144', '93248', '93170', '92946', '93065', '93136', '93283', '93296'],
                    'selectedTimeIds': ['179', '184', '217', '222'],
                    }
        return [scrapy.FormRequest(self.url,
                                   formdata=form_data,
                                   callback=self.parse_data)]

    def parse_data(self, response):
        table_headers = response.xpath('//tr[@class="BackGroundTRHeader"]/th/a/text()').extract()
        table_headers = [i.strip() for i in table_headers if i.strip()][1:]
        values = response.xpath('//tr[td[div[@class="varNameClass" and contains(text(), "Gross Domestic Product At Current Market Prices")]]]/td[@class="TextRowRight divResize"]')
        gdp_values = []
        for value in values:
            data = value.xpath('.//text()').extract()
            data = data[0].strip() if data else ''
            gdp_values.append(data)
        processed_data = dict(zip(table_headers, gdp_values))
```

instead of the usual scrapy `Request` use `FormRequest`, and updated the formdata to scrap only `2014 Q1-Q4`. Make sure you have updated the `token` in the formdata which you can grab from the browser.

Comment: Great! But is it possible to focus only on 2014 Q1-Q4?

Comment: I not sure where my code went wrong. I followed your way to do but unable to print the processed_data. Attached the image of my code here: http://tinypic.com/r/sw7acz/8

Comment: updated the code and change the token in the formdata to get the desired result. This token might have expired.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and help! Btw, was just wondering if scrapy can crawl without using command line? For example: initialising an object and call it to crawl.

Comment: [this](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script) might help, please have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway last question, how do I store it into a file? I tried to add another sentence "return processed_data" at the back of "processed_data = dict(zip(table_headers, gdp_values))" and run scrapy crawl gdp -o test.csv but got this error. Refer to image: http://tinypic.com/r/2m31vsl/8

Comment: that command will only if you are returning any Item class object. make the necessary entities in items.py and import them and create an object of item class them map the required field and return/yield item.